# How can I make the dynamic rows of a table a standard height?

Tags: html, css

I have a table where the table rows are populated dynamically. When the rows are displayed in the table each row takes up the full height of the table divided by however many rows there are. I wanted to have all equal height rows so to achieve this I added `display: block;` to the `<table>`

By default, my table starts off this the following but then with some jquery I remove the first row `remove_table_row1` and fill it with actual data.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table1_container">
        <tr class="remove_table_row1">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    min-height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Problem is when I add `display: block;` to the table it causes the table row width to shorten like so, but the height is fine.

[image]

If I remove `display: block;` from the table then the rows are full width again but the height of the rows fills up the entire height of the table. The more rows I add the shorter they get.

[image]

How can I achieve the ability for the rows to be full width and standard height of a row?

Comment: I wouldn't mess with the default display type. Did you try simply setting heights on the rows?

Comment: I did, had no effect.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. You may have to provide a complete demo (with your script). [Here's a start](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hqz2krdo/).

Comment: if display:block solve everything except width, have you tried adding width: 100%? As @isherwood it's not clear what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using display: inline-block instead of block allows you to control the width.

Comment: The width isn't what was mentioned as being the problem.

Comment: "Problem is when I add display: block; to the table it causes the table row width to shorten like so, but the height is fine." First thing mentioned was the width adjusting and the height being fine, but I should clarify that inline-block allows control over width and height.

Comment: It's just a bad approach to begin with to change the display property of the table. The original problem was row height. I'd prefer to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what did you do to add rows dynamically

but you can count rows before adding the row and then change the entire table height
by some thing like *every time adding a row*

```
table.height = (rowsCount + 1) * heightOfEachRow
```

**Attention:** share your "dynamically adding row" code to help you in code!

**Note**: you don't need to use display: block or ... else.